# Difference between "calculus" and "calculi"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between *calculus* and *calculi*?

Both of these words are used to identify formal languages in computer science (e.g. π-calculus, λ-calculus, process calculi).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Calculus** is singular.

**Calculi** is plural.

> "Predicate calculus is the same as first order logic"
>
> "Process calculi are used to analyze temporal properties of systems"

This is the direct borrowing from Latin of their pluralization of 2nd declension '-us' words, in the same class as 'alumnus (sg), alumni (pl)'. Not all foreign language borrowings maintain the original language's morphological rules, but this one does.

Comment: To explain further, from *[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_calculus)*, "In computer science, the process calculi (or process algebras) are a diverse family of related approaches to formally modelling concurrent systems. ... Leading examples of process calculi include CSP, CCS, ACP, and LOTOS. More recent additions to the family include the π-calculus, the ambient calculus, PEPA and the fusion calculus." So **process calculi** refers to a family of things, some of which are named a "calculus".

Comment: The plural **calculuses** is also accepted.

Comment: this is a site about english and not classics, right?

Comment: At arxiv.org, Google says that **calculi** is more frequent than **calculuses** by a factor of 100; **calculuses** may be accepted by some dictionaries, but it is barely used in technical contexts.